# Passing a BLOB to an Oracle procedure in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, parameters, blob, procedure

I need to pass two blobs to an Oracle procedure through a PHP file. But this is quite a trouble...

If i do the next, it doesn't work:

```
$db_query = new DB_Procedure(
                            "BEGIN
                             MY_PRC(        
                                    :p_id,
                                    :p_email,
                                    :p_image1,
                                    :p_image2
                                   );
                             END;");

$param = array (
                ':p_id' => $p_id,
                ':p_email' => $p_email,
                ':p_image1' => $image1,     
                ':p_image2' => $image2
               );

$res = $db_query->execute_query($param);
```

And it neither work this way:

```
$db_query = new DB_Procedure(
                             "BEGIN
                             MY_PRC(        
                                    :p_id,
                                    :p_email,
                                    ".$image1.",
                                    ".$image2."
                                    );
                             END;");

$param = array (
                ':p_id' => $p_id,
                ':p_email' => $p_email
               );

$res = $db_query->execute_query($param);
```

I was able to UPLOAD/INSERT BLOB's into Tables this way:

```
$sql = "UPDATE MY_TABLE
        SET b_image = empty_blob()
        WHERE           p1 = :p1
        AND             p2 = :p2
        RETURNING b_image INTO :blobdata";

$param = array (':p1' => 'something 1', ':p2' => 'something 2');
$param_blob = array(":blobdata" => null);

$db_query = new DB_Query();
$db_query->setQuery($sql);

$db_query->do_query($param,OCI_ASSOC,$param_array = null,$param_blob);

$param_blob[":blobdata"]->write($p_image);

$db_query->db_commit();
$param_blob[":blobdata"]->close();
```

But I don't know how to use this to call the procedure correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'Temporary LOBs'.  From p 238 of [The Underground PHP & Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html)

```
$myblobid = 125;
$myv = 'a very large amount of binary data';
$s = oci_parse($c, 'begin inproc(:myblobid, :myblobdata); end;');
$lob = oci_new_descriptor($c, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':MYBLOBID', $myblobid);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':MYBLOBDATA', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
$lob->writeTemporary($myv, OCI_TEMP_BLOB);
oci_execute($s);
```

The Underground Manual also shows how to get LOBs out of PL/SQL.